# Are there any up-to-date Ruby Gems providing gem templates?

Tags: ruby, templates, rubygems

I need a Ruby Gem that's up-to-date providing a template to make your own Ruby project. I've checked out one called "newgem" as well as installed it, however with the Ruby Gem template changes it no longer works. Is there any straight-forward gem template utilities for the job that are still up-to-date? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby : How to write a gem?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194547/ruby-how-to-write-a-gem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use bundler to create skeleton for a gem. See this [asciicast](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/245-new-gem-with-bundler).

Comment: Link broken, use `bundle gem your-gem-name`

Comment: Now is a good time to point out that ruby names have meaning. Investigate them before choosing a name.