# Making my first gem - Where do I start?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

So I have this idea for a RubyGem that I think would be an awesome experience to learn more about Ruby and Rails but...I have no idea where to start.

My idea is to generate a folder "articles" where you can put markdown files. From this folder the main blog page displays only the titles as links to the articles themselves.

It sounds simple but I honestly have no idea where to start. What articles do you recommend I read if I want to insert lines into routes.rb, generate a folder and display markdown in Rails?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194547/ruby-how-to-write-a-gem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend one of these tutorials for gem creation:

- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/gem-creation-with-bundler/
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/245-new-gem-with-bundler

To modify the routes.rb file, you'll just need `File.open` to read lines in. Use regular expressions to determine where you want to insert your line, and write the file back out.

To create a folder, look at the documentation for [Dir.new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-new)

For Markdown in Ruby/Rails, I like the rdiscount gem: https://github.com/rtomayko/rdiscount

Railties provide a nice way to do certain things like this.  You'll probably use http://api.rubyonrails.org quite a bit.  There is some Railtie documentation on that site here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Railtie.html.

Comment: I think rewriting source code isn't a good solution. Railsties lets you do a lot of this sort of stuff.

Comment: A *little* late, but just want to say thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend reading the [RubyGems guides](http://guides.rubygems.org/) – especially [`What is a gem?`](http://guides.rubygems.org/what-is-a-gem),  [`Make your own gem`](http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/) and [`Patterns`](http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns).

Since you're likely already using [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/), you can run [`bundle gem <name>`](http://gembundler.com/rubygems.html) to generate a gem project with stuff already in place. It does save work, but refer to the guides if there's something you don't understand.

Also, watch some [open source projects on GitHub](https://github.com/languages/Ruby) – observing other developers and taking note of how they do things certainly helps.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is probably to read other gems that do anything similar to what you want to accomplish. Start with their `.gemspec` files that will list all the other files which are needed for the gem to work, and a list of gem dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Responding more to how to get started with creating gems, the following are 2 popular, documented gems that can help you.

1. https://github.com/seattlerb/hoe
2. https://github.com/technicalpickles/jeweler

Also, though it does more than you're trying to do with your gem *(it's a static site generator)*, https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll is a very popular gem which you place `.markdown` files into a `posts/` directory which are converted to static HTML pages via rake. I would imagine you could find at least some functionality you're after there.